# Why is Babel throwing an error in my vue.js component?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

```
<template>
  <div emptyDiv>
    <h3> Stages </h3>
    <table :style="tableStyle">
      <tbody>
        <template v-for="item in jobs">
          <tr>
            <td v-for="stage in item.stage_exec" :style="getStyle(stage.build_id)" :title="stage.build_id" >
              [[ stage.cleanDuration ]]
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
  delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
  props: ['jobs'],
  computed: {
    tableStyle() {
      return {
        'background-color': '#f9f9f9',
        'border-color': '#C0C0C0',
        'padding': '8px',
        'width': '100%',
        'display': 'table',
        'table-layout': 'fixed',
      };
    },
    emptyDiv() {
      return {
        'display': 'contents',
      };
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getStyle (name) {
      switch (name) {
        case 'SUCCESS':
        return {
          'background-color': '#dff0d8',
          'padding': '10px',
          'line-height': '1.42857143',
          'border': '1px solid #C0C0C0',
        }
        case 'FAILURE':
        return {
          'background-color': '#f45942',
          'padding': '10px',
          'line-height': '1.42857143',
          'border': '1px solid #C0C0C0',
        }
      }
    },
  },
  filters: {
    durationReadable: function(duration) {
      milliseconds = parseInt((duration%1000)/100)
      seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
      minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
      if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes
      }
      if (seconds < 10){
        seconds = '0' + seconds
      }
      return minutes + " m " + seconds + " s " + milliseconds + ' ms'
      }
  },
  created() {
    testEndpoint = 'http://testurl'
    fetch(testEndpoint)
    .then(body => {
      cleanStartTime = moment(body[0].time_start)
      cleanEndTime = moment(body[0].time_end)
      cleanDuration = this.calculateDuration(cleanStartTime, cleanEndTime)
      this.job_execs.push({
        'name': body[0].job.name,
        'build_id': body[0].build_id,
        'env': body[0].job.env,
        'time_start': cleanStartTime.format('LLL'),
        'time_end': cleanEndTime.format
      })
    })
    .catch( err => {
      this.isEmpty = (this.binaries.length == 0) ? true : false;
      console.log('Error Fetching:', testEndpoint, err);
      return { 'failure': testEndpoint, 'reason': err };
    },
},
</script>
```

When I try to serve my component, it is failing to compile and I keep getting a babel error that I cannot figure out.

```
Unexpected token (117:2)
  115 |       return { 'failure': testEndpoint, 'reason': err };
  116 |     },
> 117 | 



Unexpected token (117:2)

  115 |       return { 'failure': testEndpoint, 'reason': err };
  116 |     },
> 117 |   },
      |   ^
  118 | };
  119 |
```

So what is the unexpected token?

Comment: You're missing a closing paren.

Comment: same error when i add paren

Comment: ... Where did you add it? Most IDEs/editors will show you exactly where the syntax starts to go bad.

Comment: You're also missing a comma, and looks like another closing paren. I mean, maybe take some time to clean things up, indent consistently, etc.

Comment: There is a comma missing at the end of filters and before `created(). Then the closing parentheses for catch will make sense.

Comment: Is there any IDE that will just automatically fix these?  I am using sublime text with vue component syntax highlighting, which apparently isn't helping me.

Comment: "Automatically" fixing errors like this can be difficult because it sometimes requires guessing intent. This is manually fixable in minutes by going over each line, indenting correctly, and figuring out what context your current code is in. An automated indenter will also help locate problems.

Comment: if i highlight a bracket in sublime, it will also highlight the matching bracket.  Going off of that I have all the closing brackets I need.

Comment: Great, then you have it worked out. Good work.

Comment: Same babel error

Comment: `.catch(` opens a parentheses, where are you closing it? Where the error message is pointing at the comma it expects `)`.

Comment: jason that was it - thank you